# Pearson Correlation problem

Tags: information-retrieval, correlation, collaborative-filtering, pearson

I'm not sure which figures to use below in a problem Im trying to solve that involves using the Pearson Correlation formula.

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F
Bob 4  5     4  2
Fra 2  2     2  3  2
Lee 2  4  3        5
Cha 5  4     4  1
```

"Describe a neighbourhood based approach using Pearson Correlation and weighted averages to generate a prediction for whether Bob will like "F". Your answer should outline the main steps in the neighbourhood based approach and show the steps required to generate the prediction"

So I want to find out if Bob will like F... (5=Like 1=Dislike)
I understand the Pearson Formula but I'm not sure what other 'User' to compare Bob with, or if I'm supposed to consider the views of all users.

I also understand how the answering of homework-like questions is discouraged but I have spent hours scouring the web trying to figure this out.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to see the specifics of the question to come up with the best answer for the question itself, but one approach that would seem viable would be to compute the correlation between Bob and each other peson (Fra, Lee, and Cha), and weight their scores for F by those correlations.

In this case, since you only have scores for F for Fra and Lee, just take `(corr_(Bob, Fra) * 2 + corr_(Bob, Lee))/2`

Comment: Note that it's also possible to find the correlation between 'F', and each of 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', and 'F', and similarly find yourself with a weighted value for Bob that way as well.  I wouldn't be surprised if the correct solution to your problem uses a combination of the two mechanics.

Comment: The BelKor team in the Netflix prize a few years ago used Pearson correlation as one aspect of many inputs to their winning solution.  See their paper here: http://69.147.108.248/files/BellKorIcdm07_0.pdf.  Equation (2) on page 2 may be of particular interest to you.

Comment: I've edited the question to show exactly what's being asked. Thanks